# How to install packages ( like copy-paste packages into sites-packages folder) Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, package, installation

I want to install some packages like `numpy` or `opencv` on Windows 7 32bit and nao humanoid robot. But I don't know how to install them without pip. Is there a way to install packages like copy-paste into sites-packages folder?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Don't. Just get `pip`. It'll make your life, and the lives of any future answerers of your Python questions on this site, much easier. Here's how on Windows:

- Download the installer script from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
- Save it somewhere as `get-pip.py`
- Open a command line and navigate to the script you just downloaded
- Run it as `python get-pip.py`

Anything else you try to do is just going to cause you more trouble.

If you really want to, you can just copy paste packages into the `site-packages` folder, and it should just work. But don't. For `opencv` in particular you're going to run into all kinds of trouble.

You can find your `site-packages` folder by running the following in a prompt:

```
python -c "import sys; print([p for p in sys.path if 'site-packages' in p])"
```

Comment: The pc has no internet connection. I need to install them manually. How can I do that

Comment: @MehmetBaki That's a different question. Is `pip` installed on the machine already? It'll still make things easier if it is